# Adding select field into laravel 5.4 register form

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I currently using laravel Auth and i want to add gender select field in register page but it returns error.

> Undefined index: gender

this is my form part in blade:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('gender') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="gender" class="col-md-4 control-label">Gender</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                            <select class="form-control">
                              <option value="0" name="gender">Male</option>
                              <option value="1" name="gender">Female</option>
                            </select>

                                @if ($errors->has('gender'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('gender') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

My `User` model:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'facebook_id', 'gender', 'avatar', 'username'
    ];
```

`RegisterController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'username' => 'required|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'gender' => 'sometimes|string',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'gender' => $data['gender'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

and this is in my migration:

```
$table->string('gender')->nullable();
```

any idea why it will not save to database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the name to the select, not to the options. Change like this

```
<select class="form-control" name="gender">
    <option value="0">Male</option>
    <option value="1">Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: same result `Undefined index: gender`

Comment: Thanks man, it works now but when i try to print gender that has selected in profile page will return 0 & 1 instead of names like `male` or `female`

Comment: change `value="0"` to `value="male"`. Whatever you put inside the value will be printed.